# Angular2 Http POST pads binary transfer

Tags: ajax, angular

I'm trying to send raw binary data (a slice of binary file) using a POST with Angular2's Http class. However on the server side the received data is padded, likely due to some client-side JSON conversion. For example 100000 bytes sent from the browser are read on the server as being 121201 bytes.

I can achieve this raw binary transfer and preserve the number of bytes received on the same server using jQuery.ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/analysis",
    data: blob,
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    error: function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
    success: function (data) {
      // do something heroic
    }
  });
```

The file is being read using FileReader API's `readAsBinaryString`. My suspicion is that I need to do something like in Angular 1 where you'd set the `transformRequest` to an empty array, so that the bytes aren't coerced to JSON. Here's the Angular2 version I have:

```
  getAnalysis = (headerBytes: any) => {
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
    this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/analysis", headerBytes, {
        headers: header
    })
        .retry(3)
        // response data, not data being sent
        .map(responseData => responseData.json())
        .subscribe(
        data => this.result = data,
        err => this.logError(err),
        () => console.log("request complete")
        );

};
```

I could just punt and do this in jQuery, but surely there's a way to do this with the new hotness?

Comment: This might not be supported yet, if you look at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-beta.1/modules/angular2/src/http/static_request.ts) on line 62 there's: `// TODO: support URLSearchParams | FormData | Blob | ArrayBuffer`...

Comment: @Sasxa nice find! I'm going to stick with `$.ajax` for now.